# How to Deprecate an Optional Field in .thrift Files?

Tags: deployment, thrift

Let's say I have a struct definition like this:

```
struct SomeStruct {
  1: optional binary content;
  2: optional binary newConetent;
}
```

What is the best practice to deprecate the first field ("content"), without affecting deployment? The deployment of the new code will be into multiple applications that is using this thrift structure? (Assuming some applications are still using the "content" field **before the deployment**)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended solution is to comment out the field but leave it in the IDL. This  prevents the field ID from becoming reused later for sth. else which then of course would produce incompatibilities.

If "in use by clients" means that they are accessing the outdated field for RPC only, that's not a problem w/regard to Thrift. Thrift will behave just like with a new field.

If however you mean that the field is used for serialization and the old data contain relevant information that needs to be converted somehow into the new format, you will have to leave the field active in the IDL. You may consider renaming the field in order to make it visible to the target audience of your IDL.

Comment: Thank you @JensG, I think so too. I think I will just rename the field from content to DEPRECATED_content.